# AWS cost explosion with "first 10 TB / month data transfer out beyond the global free tier"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudflare, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

Our costs have really exploded at AWS for a simple EC2 Wordpress installation (and MySQL RDS service) for bandwidth cost. It is listed on the AWS Bill as:

`first 10 TB / month data transfer out beyond the global free tier`

Everything (EC2, RDS, S3) is in the same AZ.
I'm new to IT administration and not quite sure how to fix this. We are already compressing all big files (e.g., images and downloadables; don't have video or other heavy content) and even gzip our HTML/CSS/JS.

I've heard that one solution could be to use a CDN, which we're not using right now. Is this really a solution and are there "free CDNs" even out there (e.g., Cloudflare, Amazon CloudFront)? Would these solve that issue or is there any other guideline to reduce that number?

[image]

Comment: Rough order of magnitude, how many requests do you serve and how big are they? You may really have 4 TB to the Internet.